# Determinant of a real skew-symmetric matrix is square of an integer

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, bilinear-form, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Let $A$ be a real skew-symmetric matrix with integer entries. Show that $\operatorname{det}{A}$ is square of an integer.

Here is my idea: If $A$ is skew-symmetric matrix of odd order, then $\operatorname{det}{A}$ is zero. So, take $A$ to be of even order and non-singular. Since all the eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $ia$ and its conjugate (where $a$ is real number), we see that $\operatorname{det}{A}$ is square of a real number. But I am not getting how to show it is square of an integer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian

Comment: I deleted my answer since it doesn't make sense. Thanks to @JasonDeVito.

Comment: Sorry,I need more explanation.I did not get the idea.

Comment: The Pfaffian is a polynomial function of the matrix entries

Comment: Just see this, my favorite proof is by using the involution principle. See Aigner's Course in combinatorics. Theorem 5.6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A proof by induction is given in David J. Buontempo, The determinant of a skew-symmetric matrix, The Mathematical Gazette, Vol. 66, No. 435, Mar., 1982, Note 66.15, pages 67-69. If you have access to jstor, it's [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/3617320). The proof does not depend on the Pfaffian.

Comment: Is it possible to include the images of the 3 pages here?

Comment: I'm certainly not going to do that. If you have access to a library, I'm sure they can get it for you on Interlibrary Loan.

Comment: Never mind, I got it legally.

Answer (score 3):

For a skew symmetric $A$, $\det(A)={\rm pfaffian}(A)^2$ where pfaffian is an integral  polynomial function of the entries of the matrix $A$. For the case of an integer matrix the pfaffian is therefore an integer. Hence the result you want.

Comment: Yes, and that information is already available at the Wikipedia/Pfaffian link in the first comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the determinant of an invertible skew-symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries.  Work over the field $\mathbb Q$ and write $n=2\cdot r$.  First observe that $\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 & I_r \\ - I_r & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} I_r&\mathbf 0 \\ \mathbf 0&- I_r \end{bmatrix}\right)\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 & I_r \\  I_r & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}\right)=(-1)^r(-1)^r=1$

Now write $B^TAB =\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 & I_r \\ - I_r & \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$ i.e. $A$ is *congruent* to the symplectic matrix; this implies $A$'s determinant is positive.

Taking determinants we get $\det\big(A\big) = \det\big(B^{-1}\big)^2$ where  $\det\big(A\big)\in \mathbb N$ (as $A$'s components are integers).  If $\big\vert \det\big(B^{-1}\big)\big\vert=\lambda$ and $\lambda \not \in \mathbb N$ then $\lambda=\frac{m}{k p}$ where $m$ modulo (prime) $p$ is non-zero (Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic) which, after clearing denominators and squaring, implies  $k^2 p^2 \cdot \det\big(A\big) =m^2$ but the RHS is non-zero mod $p$ (a unit in $\mathbb F_p$) and the LHS is zero mod $p$ which is impossible.  Conclude $\lambda \in \mathbb N$ and $\lambda^2=\det\big(A\big)$ is a squared integer.