# Calculating a determinant using Jacobi's second theorem

Tags: determinant

Prove using Jacobi's second theorem on determinants that

$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & a & b & c \\
-a & 0 & d & e \\
-b & -d & 0 & f \\
-c & -e & -f & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix} = (af-be+cd)^2$$

I can easily prove it using Laplace expansion for determinants but have no idea how to prove it using Jacobi's second theorem. A corollary of the theorem tells that the determinant would be a perfect square of a polynomial of the elements. But nothing further. Any help will be appreciated.

For the theorem, have a look here: [Jacobi's Second Theorem on Determinants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisTheorem.html)

Comment: As @Semiclassical said, this theorem is not known generally. Please give a reference.

Comment: The expression is the square of the so-called "Pffafian". You will find a very interesting (recent) answer in (https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h540072_prove_that_determinant_is_a_perfect_square).

Comment: Have a look also at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165787). For an interesting link with graph matching, see (http://math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438S14/lec4-algmat.pdf).

Comment: Is [this the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) that you're referring to? Or is it [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobisTheorem.html)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It was the Wolfram link. Thanks. I've included it in my question.